# is it possible to get public IP address using typescript without using third part links

Tags: angular, typescript

I know I am not the first to ask this question ,I am working in an Angular 4 application ,In this I need to take the public IP of my system(user system).

For that I have searched for the reference in Stackoverflow but most of the post gives the solution to consume third part API url for getting IP.

But in my case I want to programmatically trace the public IP of the user system.

I am looking for the suggestions or solution in this.

Comment: Is something in Typescript / angular refraining from applying the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841164/3702797?

Comment: @Kaiido I already tried this solution ,which returns my network IP instead of public IP

Comment: Try the [`public-ip`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/public-ip) package.

Comment: When the user loads the application, do they do so by hitting a webserver? Is the webserver under your control? If so, you might be able to get the users IP from the request sent to the webserver. Then you can write it in to the page/scripts/anything thats returned to your application. As an example, with ASP.Net you can use the HttpRequest object to [get the IP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @tony19 it worked thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`public-ip`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/public-ip) package. *Note this internally uses a third-party server to determine your public IP address, but at least that's abstracted away.*

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import publicIp from 'public-ip';

@Component({
  selector: 'public-ip',
  template: `<h1>Your public IP is {{publicIpAddr}}</h1>`
})
export class PublicIpComponent implements OnInit {
  publicIpAddr: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    publicIp.v4().then((ip) => this.publicIpAddr = ip);
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drt1nl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: If 3rd party is down.. your code breaks and we cannot depend on 3rd party without testing them thoroughly...