# Can we restrict the App Service to specific country in Azure?

Tags: azure

I have a web app hosted in Azure, i need to allow the website to be browseable only from specific countries. Is there any config settings that can be done to restrict the countries in azure.

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the issue you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Azure websites don't have an geo filtering built in, however the Azure CDN provider does have [geo filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country) so that might be something to look at. Still an extra cost, but not as bad as a WAF.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Geolocation feature which is part of one of the new preview services called Azure Maps. You can find more details about the same at [Azure Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/geolocation/geolocation_getiptolocationpreview)

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: How do i get the IP address of the user in this case? JavaScript can get the Private IP of user, but if is there a way to obtain public ip??

Comment: Which prog language are you using? C#? If yes, you can get it from the Request object. Something explained in https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/699510/Get-the-public-ip-address-of-a-client-machine-in-a link

Comment: It will be angular

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385653/is-it-possible-to-get-public-ip-address-using-typescript-without-using-third-par and https://programmingwithnaveen.com/2017/12/26/get-client-ip-in-angular/